# Нажат ли элемент с нужным классом

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть массив классов типа

```
var array_m = ['.class1','.class2'];
```

Как сделать так, чтобы:
Если на странице нажат элемент, у которого `hasClass('один_из_классов_массива')`, то вывести `alert`

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что-то +- такое, только классы в массиве без точки лучше хранить :

```js
var array = ['class1', 'class2'];

document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const containsClassFromArray = array.some(c => e.target.classList.contains(c))

  if (containsClassFromArray) {
    console.log(e.target.value)
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="button" class="class1" value="1" />
<input type="button" class="class2" value="2" />
<input type="button" class="class3" value="3" />
<input type="button" class="class4" value="4" />
```

[MDN-some](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы захватывались и родители и дети ? `parent` & `child` т.к если у элемента с нужным классом установлен `z-index` и селекторы, типа `:after`, то работает некорректно

Comment: нужен пример такой разметки где не правильно работает, или попробовать `currentTarget`

Comment: https://codeshare.io/alLvER 
Залил пример

Comment: было бы не плохо с js-кодом клика и списком классов пример...

Comment: А прям Ваш вставил, только `var array = ['mts','qiwi'];`. 
Попробовал через `$(document)` посмотреть, на что кликается - показало, что `.overlay`

Comment: Если делать просто $('.mts').click() то все работает хорошо..но делать так для 16 элементов массива..